# Apache Pig: Group operator and variable schema

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following question:
Snippet of my sample.txt. First column is id, however each row can have variable number of columns.

id1 100 200 300 400 500

id2 10 20 30

id1 800 900 600

id3 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100

id1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

id2 40 50 60 70 80 90

id3 200

sample = LOAD 'sample.txt' [how should I specify schema here]

sample_grpd = GROUP sample by $0;

sample_result = FOREACH sample_grpd generate group, FLATTEN(TOBAG([what should go here]))

group by id so that the result is:

id1 100 200 300 400 500 800 900 600 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

id2 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90

id3 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 200

Any help with this, will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Its very difficult to implement your requirement using native pig. you have to go for UDF only. Please try the below solution with your input and let me know how it works.  For your above question change your code like this "sample = LOAD 'sample.txt' USING PigStorage('  ')" and FLATTEN(TOBAG(*)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the tricky problem, finally somehow i solved it using UDF.

**input.txt**

```
id1 100 200 300 400 500
id2 10 20 30
id1 800 900 600
id3 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
id1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
id2 40 50 60 70 80 90
id3 200
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER removeduplicate.jar;
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(' ');
B = GROUP A by $0;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0 AS myid:chararray,$1 AS (B:{T:(f1:chararray)});
D = FOREACH C GENERATE myid,BagToString(B) AS concatString;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE myid,mypackage.REMOVEDUPLICATE(concatString) AS finalString;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE myid,FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(finalString,'_',40)) AS result;
STORE F INTO 'output' USING PigStorage(' ');
```

**Output:**

```
id1 100 200 300 400 500 800 900 600 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
id2 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
id3 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 200
```

**UDF CODE**  The below java class file is compiled and generated as **removeduplicate.jar**
**REMOVEDUPLICATE.java**

```
  package mypackage;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
    import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
    import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

    public class REMOVEDUPLICATE extends EvalFunc<String> {
    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple arg0) throws IOException {
           try
            {
                String input = ((String) arg0.get(0));
                    String duplicateString = input.split("\\_")[0]+"_";
                    System.out.println(duplicateString);
                    return(input.replace(duplicateString, ""));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new IOException("Caught exception while processing the input row ", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does BagToString add _ to each?

Comment: yes you are right, BagToString function will append '_' as default delimiter to each field. You can change the delimiter also something like this BagToString(mystring,delimiter);